# How to list an academic award received multiple times on CV

Tags: graduate-admissions, cv, awards

I was distinguished as 'Best Freshman' when I started university as a freshman. If, as I did, I managed to display an exceptional academic performance, I was re-awarded this distinction (which actually doubled as a scholarship). I am now preparing my CV to apply for Master's degrees. How should I list this award in my CV? I feel saying,

> Awarded 'Best Freshman' distinction in 2016, 2017 and 2018

for example, might convey the wrong idea, as I was only a freshman that first year.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: This sounds like Ben Simmons winning rookie of the year his second year in the league.

Comment: When you were re-awarded the distinction, was that for performance during the second and third years, or was it a delayed "payout" for the original award?

Comment: @Anyon, it was for my performance on the second and third years - each "award" covered only one year, and it was up to me to maintain a good enough level to be chosen again the following year

Comment: Perhaps you need to wordsmith it to keep the spirit of the award even if you stray from the specifics.  
`Recognized for exceptional academic performance (2016, 2017, 2018)`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The name of this award is directly misleading. That's on the university. I would simply state "Recipient of full-ride academic scholarship 2015, 2016, 2017. Awarded for maintaining at least a 3.85 GPA over the previous two semesters of each school year."

This is the most likely way to convey the meaning you want. It is clearer to just state *what* the award actually entailed. This will always translate across regions and schools.

I remember seeing an application of one student that stated she was the "Donald M. Knudsun Honor recipient." This turned out to be a $100 gift certificate to Knudsun's, a local steak house. (I knew Don Knudsun owned a steak house, so it sounded like a weird award to begin with, hence my inquiring into the details). It had essentially nothing to do with her academics. You won the award for answering trivia while eating bratwurst.

Comment: "answering trivia while eating bratwurst" seems multidisciplinary

Comment: Not everyone would understand what "full-ride" means. I'm only guessing, for example; I've never heard that term before. Maybe you get a full ride around town in the award funder's car?

Comment: @einpoklum Agreed - it sounds like something that would be done by consenting adults in private, not publicised in one's CV!

Comment: @einpoklum I have heard the term many times in the United States. Numerous results come up on Google, none of which have to do with cars and consenting adults. The OP can of course mold the wording as he or she sees fit.